# Count Distinct Persons Per Year, but Only Once

Tags: sql-server, sas

How would I select distinct persons per year, but only count each person once.

An example of my data is:

```
ID Date
1 20NOV2018    
2 06JUN2017    
2 29JUL2011    
3 05MAY2014    
4 04APR2002    
4 25APR2009
```

I want my output to look like:

```
2002 1    
2009 0    
2011 1    
2014 1    
2017 0     
2018 1
```

Comment: Is it SAS SQL or can you use a different type of SQL? I suspect that SQL tag is incorrect.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Use sub-selects to left join the distinct years with the first year an id occurs and count the ids from that.

```
data have;
input 
id date date9.; format date date9.; datalines;
1 20NOV2018
2 06JUN2017
2 29JUL2011
3 05MAY2014
4 04APR2002
4 25APR2009
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select each.year, count(first.id) as appeared_count
  from
    ( select distinct year(date) as year 
      from have
    ) as each
  left join
    ( select id, min(year(date)) as year
      from have group by id 
    ) as first
  on each.year = first.year
  group by each.year
  order by each.year
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Code Works Fine for Your case:

```sql
SELECT YEAR(M.DATE) AS DATE,COUNT(S.ID)
FROM @TAB M
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(YEAR(DATE)) AS DATE ,ID
            FROM @TAB GROUP BY ID) S ON YEAR(M.DATE)=S.DATE GROUP BY YEAR(M.DATE) ORDER BY YEAR(M.DATE)
```